# Как растянуть aside по высоте родительского блока без js и flex?

Tags: html, css, height

Есть примерно такой html:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  ...

  <aside></aside>

</div>
```

Высота блоку #wrapper не задана, поскольку она динамически меняется в зависимости от появления и удаления section. Как на чистом css растянуть aside (зафлоачен справа) по всей высоте #wrapper? Чтобы высота aside, соответственно, тоже динамически изменялась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с `position: absolute` :

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper__left {
  padding-right: 220px;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper__left">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
  </div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper:after {
  clear:both;
  content: '';
  display:block;
}

.wrapper__inner {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

section {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside>
    <div class="wrapper__inner">
      <section>1</section>
      <section>2</section>
      <section>3</section>
      <section>4</section>
      <section>5</section>
      <section>6</section>
    </div>
    <div class="aside__inner">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `display: table`.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper__left {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

aside {
  background: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper__left">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
  </div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```