# Высота aside по по высоте родительского div'a

Tags: html, css

Не могу растянуть боковую панель по высоте родительского div'a. Пробовал использовать варианты приведенные в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616854/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-aside-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-js-%D0%B8-flex), но блок ставится с правой стороны(хотя надо с левой).
Еще пробовал такой вариант:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute; 
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Но тогда блок вообще пропадает.
По сути все блоки должны иметь высоту по родительского блока.
P.S. Все манипуляции проводил с левым желтым блоком.

[image: Скриншот]

Исходный код:

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
/* End of Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
body {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Begin of styles for the demo (you can remove them) */

a.expand {
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
a.expand:hover {
  height: 500px;
}
/* End of of styles for the demo */

.wrapper {
  min-width: 460px;
  max-width: 1450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.middle {
  position: relative;
  padding: 73px 71px 73px 72px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(250, 226, 143, 1), rgba(250, 239, 202, 1));
}
.container {
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}
.container:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.content {
  float: left;
  width: 685px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Left Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.left-sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 115px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffd703;
}
/* Right Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.right-sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 207px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.right-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #efefef;
}
/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.footer {
  height: 365px;
  background: #BFF08E;
}
#navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
#navbar li {} #navbar a {
  color: #af9300;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: Vollkorn;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">

    <div class="container">
      <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <h1>Hotel V</h1>
        <ul id="navbar">
          <li><a href="#">Find a hotel</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Meeting & Events</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About Hotel</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <!-- .left-sidebar -->

      <aside class="right-sidebar">
        <strong>Right Sidebar:</strong> Integer velit. Vestibulum nisi nunc, accumsan ut, vehicula sit amet, porta a, mi. Nam nisl tellus, placerat eget, posuere eget, egestas eget, dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. In elementum urna a eros. Integer iaculis. Maecenas vel elit.
      </aside>
      <!-- .right-sidebar -->

      <main class="content">
        <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa.
        Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit
        lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit.
      </main>
      <!-- .content -->

      <aside class="right-menu">
        <strong>Right Sidebar:</strong> Integer velit. Vestibulum nisi nunc, accumsan ut, vehicula sit amet, porta a, mi. Nam nisl tellus, placerat eget, posuere eget, egestas eget, dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. In elementum urna a eros. Integer iaculis. Maecenas vel elit.
      </aside>
    </div>
    <!-- .container-->
  </div>
  <!-- .middle-->
</div>
<!-- .wrapper -->
```

Comment: Флексбоксом? В том ответе такие пляски с бубном нужны были по причине невозможности его использования.

Comment: нет, у родительского ставил relative а у дочернего absolute.

Comment: я имею в виду, решение на флексбоксе вам подходит?

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял суть вопроса, с флексбоксами не встречался и не знаю что это такое, просветите?

Comment: Все, нашел, большое спасибо за ваш ответ. Одним свойством все поправилось!

Comment: очевидно, это не дубликат, поскольку условия "без js и flex" тут нет.

Comment: @Vadizar, если бы это был дубликат того вопроса то какой смысл мне приводить его же в содержании? Перечитайте внимательно вопрос.

Comment: @edvardpotter я видел, вы просто не сообразили left: 0 поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `position: absolute` :

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper__left {
  padding-left: 220px;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper__left">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
    <section>4</section>
    <section>5</section>
  </div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```